# How to specify where clause using result from another select statement without knowing exactly what columns are returned the select statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

SQL newbie, so pardon if this is a silly question.

I have one table which contains a list of "filters" to be used in a query on another table. What'd I like to do is something like this:

```
select firstname, lastname from tblNames (nolock) names
where (select filter from tblFilterInfo (nolock) filters
where filters.ID = 12 and filter.Type = 3)
```

The inner select would return this

```
firstname like 'j%'
firstname like 's%'
lastname like 't%'
```

Which is then what I'd like to use in the outer where clause.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is intended in the language. Might be something available in a specific database dialect. What DB are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Obviously :) what I need to end up with is this:                                       select firstname, lastname from tblNames (nolock) names
where firstname like 'j%' or firstname like 's%' or lastname like 't%'

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... :)